# Static object holding the values from the previous request and sending duplicate message

Tags: c#

I have a service that sends the notification to the discord service, but we notice that most of the time it is sending the duplicate payload to the discord.

We are running the **DiscordService** from a [hangfire job](https://www.hangfire.io/).

I took out the code that sends the discord message and added a simple log.

```cs
public class DiscordService : IDiscordService
{
    private readonly ILogger<DiscordService> _logger;
    private static OrderRequestModel orderRequest;
    public static ulong ChannelId;
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly string _token;
    public DiscordService(ILogger<DiscordService> logger, IOptions<DiscordSettingModel> discordSettingModel, ISignalDbContext dbSignalDbContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _client.Ready += OnReady;

        _token = discordSettingModel.Value.Token;

    }
    private async Task StartDiscord()
    {
        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _token);
        await _client.StartAsync();
    }
    private async Task OnReady()
    {
        //this method sends the request to the discord
        _logger.LogInformation($"timeframe-value {orderRequest.TimeFrame}");

        //my original code looks like this 

        //var chnl = _client.GetChannel(ChannelId) as IMessageChannel;
        //var builder = new EmbedBuilder();
        //    builder
        //      .WithDescription("⚠️ Alert! ⚠️")
        //      .WithColor(new Color(33, 176, 252))
        //      .AddField(" Order Action", orderRequest.OrderAction, false)
        //      .AddField("⏰ Order Date/Time", orderRequest.Time, false)
        //      .AddField("⏳ TIF", orderRequest.TIF, false);
        

        //var embed = builder.Build();
        //await chnl.SendMessageAsync(null, false, embed);

    }

    public async Task SendMessage(OrderRequestModel model, ulong channelId)
    {
        orderRequest = model;
        ChannelId = channelId;
        await StartDiscord();
    }
 }
```

This service is being called as:

```
await _discordService.SendMessage(orderRequestModel, categoryData.ChannelId);
```

After running the following code, I noticed that such behavior was caused due to the use of static object `orderRequest`.

I have also posted the log generated.

```
[11:15:03 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 335.4498 ms
[11:15:04 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 4.3690 ms
[11:15:05 INF] timeframe-value 104m
[11:15:06 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 8.2411 ms
[11:15:08 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 4.1984 ms
[11:15:10 INF] timeframe-value 105m
[11:15:11 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 5.2062 ms
[11:15:12 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 6.1026 ms
[11:15:14 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 10.4395 ms
[11:15:16 INF] timeframe-value 107m
[11:15:17 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 4.5805 ms
[11:15:19 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 6.5317 ms
[11:15:21 INF] HTTP POST /api/record/webhook responded 200 in 4.9942 ms
[11:15:27 INF] timeframe-value 110m
[11:15:33 INF] timeframe-value 110m
[11:15:39 INF] timeframe-value 110m
[11:15:45 INF] timeframe-value 110m
[11:15:52 INF] timeframe-value 110m
[11:15:58 INF] timeframe-value 110m
[11:16:03 INF] timeframe-value 110m
```

What could be the reason for causing this behaviour by the object being static? This code is not written by me and it was already running on production. So, how can I fix this?

Comment: you have declared static model and ChannelId but it is not used where in the class... so it doesn't look like that's the issue...

Comment: that is being used in `OnReady()` method

Comment: OnReady is executed when `SendMessage` is called?

Comment: yeah the code ` await StartDiscord();` calls `OnReady `

Comment: How do you confirm that the duplicate payload is being sent?

Comment: in the discord messages and it is in the log as well.